# TemplateSyntaxError at / 'avatar_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, avatar

One django project code works well in my friend's PC, while failed in mine with the following error. virturalenv is setup successfully, and I can find avatar-tags.py under 
[virtualenv-folder]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avatar/templatetags. Does anyone know what's reason on this? Thanks a lot.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

'avatar_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library avatar_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.avatar_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.avatar_tags,django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.avatar_tags,pinax.templatetags.templatetags.avatar_tags,pinax_theme_bootstrap.templatetags.avatar_tags,staticfiles.templatetags.avatar_tags,compressor.templatetags.avatar_tags,timezones.templatetags.avatar_tags,announcements.templatetags.avatar_tags,pagination.templatetags.avatar_tags,idios.templatetags.avatar_tags,metron.templatetags.avatar_tags,django_extensions.templatetags.avatar_tags,tagging.templatetags.avatar_tags,account.templatetags.avatar_tags

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

'avatar_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library avatar_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.avatar_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.avatar_tags,django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.avatar_tags,pinax.templatetags.templatetags.avatar_tags,pinax_theme_bootstrap.templatetags.avatar_tags,staticfiles.templatetags.avatar_tags,compressor.templatetags.avatar_tags,timezones.templatetags.avatar_tags,announcements.templatetags.avatar_tags,pagination.templatetags.avatar_tags,idios.templatetags.avatar_tags,metron.templatetags.avatar_tags,django_extensions.templatetags.avatar_tags,tagging.templatetags.avatar_tags,account.templatetags.avatar_tags

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1054
Python Executable:  /Users/Yandongqiao/Documents/memor_code/memor-env/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.1
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the `avatar` app is not in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting--note that `avatar.templatetags.avatar_tags` does not appear in the template tag search path.

Comment: Thanks Michael. You are right and I find the problem. Something in INSTALLED_APPS of my local_settings.py override those in settings.py. I remove those in local_settings.py then it works.